# I am making a project in html and was wondering if it is possible to import a .py file into the html code

Tags: python, html

Is it possible to import a .py file into html code as a link. if so how do you do it. I have tried link rel="import" href="___.py" but this does not work.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you rephrase or expand on this question? Are you trying to run a Python file from HTML? Or just create a normal link to the contents of the file? If the latter, a standard `<a href="filename.py">` will do it. But when you say you want to "import" a .py file into HTML, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Im sorry I am a noob with html, when you do <a href="filename.py> how do you make it into a url on the page

Comment: If you haven't yet learned how to make a basic `<a>` link, you need an HTML tutorial, not a question about importing Python files. [This one](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/) is decent, though instead of using Notepad like they suggest I would recommend something like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) -- using Notepad for *any* serious HTML work is like tying one hand behind your back before you start working. At any rate, once you've gone through that tutorial you'll have a better understanding of what I said about `<a href="filename.py">`.

Answer (score 1):

rel attributes do not include "import". http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

may be you should have a look up psp (python server pages) technology, but it is not a recommended way of developing web apllications - because logic and presentation are mixed in a file.

example code

```
<html>
<%
import math
%>
<h1>square root of 25 is <%= math.sqrt(25) %> </h1>
</html>
```

you can import your own python modules/scripts such way

**foo.py**

```
my_var = "bar"
```

**example.html**

```
<html>
<%
import foo
%>
<h1>my var is <%= foo.my_var %> </h1>
</html>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-server-pages

http://webware.sourceforge.net/Webware/PSP/Docs/